# Updating crontab of a user (non interactive)

Tags: cron

I want to update the crontab of a linux user. In the past I have done this interactively via ssh and `crontab -e`.

I want to automate this.

My needs: I need to update crontabs. This means I need a unique name for each entry. Otherwise the tool can't distinguish between an "add" and a "update".

The problem: I can't handle the crontab of the user as whole file. I need to be able to update each part on its own ...

My perfect solution would look like this:

`magic-crontab-tool add-or-update unique-name-for-this crontab-snippet.file`

file crontab-snippet.file:

```
@hourly do-x
@weekly do-y
```

The result should look like this (`crontab -l`)

```
# Start manged by magic-crontab-tool. ID: unique-name-for-this
@hourly do-x
@weekly do-y
# End unique-name-for-this
```

## Background:

All of this needs to be done as normal user, not root access available.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the target system is one that has `run-parts` I would do as follows. First create a single line in the user's crontab, if it is not already there. It could look like this:

```
@hourly cd /home/user && run-parts --report /home/user/.cron.hourly
```

Multiple lines could be created if different schedules are needed such as `hourly`, `daily`, `weekly`, `monthly`, and `yearly`.

Then inside the `/home/user/.cron.hourly` you can create files as needed, each of which is named according to your naming scheme.

This approach is essentially replicating what certain distributions (such as Ubuntu) already do in `/etc/crontab`. The difference is that only `root` can update `/etc/crontab`, but you are looking for something which each user can set up for themselves.

Comment: Yes, this could work. It needs modification at root level, but only once. I would do it like this: ~/.cron.* gets sourced like normal crontab lines (the time to start needs to be inside) and ~/.cron.(hourly|daily|...).* gets sourced like you explained. It would be nice if something like this would be available without custom scripting.

Comment: @guettli My suggestion does not require `root` to do anything. It is entirely possible for a user to do this by themselves.

Comment: yes, you are right. I have seen run-parts only at "root-level" before. But it could be executed as normal user, too. Unfortunately I need to support several distributions and run-parts is not available on SuSE-Linux :-(

Answer (score 0):

create uniq filenames in one directory, modify any file, then add all to crontab:

```
cat *.file | crontab
```

Comment: This would destroy entries which are done outside this system.